# migrate to new domain server, new sql instance

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-migration

I have problem during migration of TFS. I have old server with old SQL instance and  TFS, i am moving TFS application with database to new one. I followed this approach: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936138.aspx

In the end I had  TFS on new server, attached collection, new SQL instance. Problem was with every collection, in every one I had SQL instance of old server, not new one. I tried editing, but ended with errors.

I read somewhere, that apart from collection, i also should move Tfs_Configuration DB, can it be a solution?

Maybe moving collection to SQL server instance, and also reinstalling TFS on new machine needs some other steps?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".